# Funny, Jewish sci-fi novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi, humor

I read it mid 80's and found it a few years ago, but with the publication of a new Jewish sci-fi novel, it's harder to find it again.

The story is about an investigator working for a government agency regulating technology or some such.

He has a bag of tricks and complains towards the end that the antagonist has something better.

He also had an alien monkey sidekick IIRC. Something of an ace in the hole.

Lots of Jewish, Yiddish phrases including Sitra Achra. It's a funny novel, filled with jokes and humor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took forever but I think I found it.

Based on [Good Reads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1867008.The_Tsaddik_of_the_Seven_Wonders), it is the The Tsaddik of the Seven Wonders by Isidore Haiblum.

- *I read it mid 80's.* Published 1971.
- *The story is about an investigator working for a government agency regulating technology or some such.* It's regulating time travel.
- *He also had an alien monkey sidekick IIRC. Something of an ace in the hole.* This is Greenberg the homunculus.
- *Lots of Jewish, Yiddish phrases including Sitra Achra. It's a funny novel, filled with jokes and humor.* The reviews mention it's full of kooky humor.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. :) Congrats!

Comment: I want to try and see if I can read a snippet online to verify it 100%. I planned on doing it already and life intervened.

Comment: It looks like it's going to be difficult to get a hold of a copy. I'm going to accept it.